# gstreamer custom plugin for nvidia gpu

Tags: gpu, gstreamer, nvidia

I want to develop a gstreamer plugin that can use the acceleration provided by the GPU of the graphics card (NVIDIA RTX2xxx). The objective is to have a fast gstreamer pipeline that process a video stream including on it a custom filter.

After two days googling, I can not find any example or hint.

1. One of the best alternatives found is use "nvivafilter", passing a cuda module as argument. However, no where explains how to install this plugin or provides an example. Worst, it seems that it could be specific for Nvidia Jetson hardware.
2. Another alternative seems use gstreamer inside an opencv python script. But that means a mix that I do not known how impacts performance.
3. This gstreamer [tutorial](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/playback/hardware-accelerated-video-decoding.html?gi-language=c) talks about several libraries. But seems outdated and not provides details.
4. RidgeRun seems to have something similar to "nvivafilter", but not FOSS.

Has someone any example or suggestion about how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you start with installing DS 5.0 and explore the examples and the apps provided. It's built on Gstreamer. [Deepstream](https://developer.nvidia.com/deepstream-sdk) [Instalation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/dev-guide/index.html)

The installation is straight forward. You will find custom parsers built.
You will need to install the following: `Ubuntu 18.04`, `GStreamer 1.14.1`, `NVIDIA driver 440`or later,`CUDA 10.2`,`TensorRT 7.0` or later.

Here is an example of running an app with 4 streams. `deepstream-app -c /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/source4_1080p_dec_infer-resnet_tracker_sgie_tiled_display_int8.txt`

The advantage of DS is that all the video pipeline is optimized on GPU including decoding and preprocessing. You can always run `Gstreamer` along `opencv` only, in my experience it's not an efficient implementation.

**Building custom parsers:**
The parsers are required to convert the raw Tensor data from the inference to (x,y) location of bounding boxes around the detected object. This post-processing algorithm will vary based on the detection architecture.
If using Deepstream 4.0, Transfer Learning Toolkit 1.0 and TensorRT 6.0: follow the instructions in the repository https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_4.x_apps

If using Deepstream 5.0, Transfer Learning Toolkit 2.0 and TensorRT 7.0: keep following the instructions from https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_tlt_apps

**Resources:**

1. Starting page: https://developer.nvidia.com/deepstream-sdk
2. Deepstream download and resources: https://developer.nvidia.com/deepstream-getting-started
3. Quick start manual: https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/dev-guide/index.html
4. Integrate TLT model with Deepstream SDK: https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_tlt_apps
5. Deepstream Devblog: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/building-iva-apps-using-deepstream-5.0/
6. Plugin manual: https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/plugin-manual/index.html
7. Deepstream 5.0 release notes: https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/DeepStream_5.0_Release_Notes.pdf
8. Transfer Learning Toolkit v2.0 Release Notes: https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/TLT/tlt-release-notes/index.html
9. Transfer Learning Toolkit v2.0 Getting Started Guide: https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/TLT/tlt-getting-started-guide/index.html
10. Metropolis documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/
11. TensorRT: https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt
12. TensorRT documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html
13. TensorRT Devblog: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/speeding-up-deep-learning-inference-using-tensorrt/
14. TensorRT Open Source Software: https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT
15. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/base/gstbasetransform.html?gi-language=cGood luck.

Comment: In your opinion, Is it possible to use deep stream for custom app? for example : face recognition
That's mean I want to use decode multi-stream and one detector of deep stream for face detection, but for face recognition, the deep stream doesn't support any model for this task, I want to know How I can integrated the face rec system to deep steam? I want to get outputs like counting and coordinates of deep stream, Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can. You have two level of complexity most of the time. You will need first to optimize your model and convert to TRT. If its a supported model its straight forward, then you will need to build your app parser. Now if model not supported you may need to write your own plugins and do some surgery. In your case, I suggest this Tutorial (DetectNet) includes faceNet pre-trained model. Also I suggest to use DS Docker containers, it will save you time. https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference/blob/master/docs/detectnet-training.md#locating-object-coordinates-using-detectnet

Comment: Thanks so much, I tested some examples and apps of deep stream on jetson platform, but my problem is that, DS used nvinfer plugin for inference the models such as classification and detection and segmentation. but If I want to use my custom network like face recognition, How the nvinfer of DS support from my model? the face rec scheme is not in the DS and nvinfer plugin. How do I can to support the custom model like face recognition? I have to white custom plugin for my model like nvinfer?

Comment: If possible answer the questions and see that link in the nvidia forms:https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/some-question-about-deep-stream-5/125528/37?u=lovenvidia

Comment: You are right. You may need to write your own plugin if model not supported. Lets say you have a complex model the trt engine build will require some work. And then write own custom parser. 
Did you check this? https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/face-detection-deepstream-sdk-4/81684

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/face-detection-deepstream-sdk-4/81684